# static bindings in DHCP server

Tags: dhcp, dhcp-server

I'd like to enable static binding in the `DHCP` server (I'm using KEA Dhcp https://www.isc.org/kea) but I think it is applicable to other implementations as well.

What exactly I want to achieve is to ensure that a client identified by its hardware address will be re-allocated the same IP address, after the client has reset. I know this can be configured on dhcp server's config file by mapping MAC address with assigned IP address.

However, can the same be done in an automatic mode? Can the server automatically build such mappings, is it available in Kea Dhcp for instance?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just configure the lease duration as -1 (infinite).
This will make sure the client will get back the IP address it was assigned upon first contact no matter how much later it comes back.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. So, from the server's point of view, this (infinite lease) makes it look like the client never needs to renew its leased IP?

Comment: Exactly. (Filler text to reach the minimum length for comments.)

Comment: Does this mean that a client will not attempt to re-new its lease? Is the client still required to rebind?

Comment: There are still situations where the client will have to reacquire its lease, such as after a reboot or if it has been connected to a different network in the mean time. But as long as no such condition occurs, most clients will indeed never attempt to renew their lease.

Comment: Then, if a client preserves the lease information between reboots, it should be able to request its "original" address, and the server should be able to satisfy such request, correct?

Comment: Correct. (Filler text to satisfy minimum comment length.)